# Do I need a transit visa traveling via Heathrow to San Francisco?

Tags: lhr, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am a citizen of Pakistan and on my way to San Francisco I have 20 hour stay at Heathrow airport.
Do I need a transit visa if I would want to stay at a hotel overnight in London heathrow?

I have a valid US visa and confirmed flight to San Francisco from London!